# How to map extended classes in MapStruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

Gotta question regarding mapStruct. I have case where I extend class from base entity and not sure how to map it. Here is my case.

BaseEntity:

```
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
}
```

BaseDto:

```
public class BaseDto {

    private Long id;
}
```

UserEntity:

```
public class User extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String profilePicturePath;
}
```

UserDto:

```
public class UserDto extends BaseDto {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String profilePicturePath;
}
```

And mapper is like this:

```
@Mapper(uses = {BaseMapper.class})
public interface UserMapper {

    User userDtoToUser(UserDto userDto);

    UserDto userToUserDto(User user);
}
```

BaseMapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface BaseMapper {

    BaseEntity dtoToEntity(BaseDto baseDto);

    BaseDto entityToDto(BaseEntity baseEntity);
}
```

Problem is that I don't get ID property mapped.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:

There is no error shown, in mapper implementation (generated code) there is no mapping for that ID:

```
 @Override
    public User userDtoToUser(UserDto userDto) {
        if ( userDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        UserBuilder user = User.builder();

        user.name( userDto.getName() );
        user.lastName( userDto.getLastName() );
        user.username( userDto.getUsername() );
        user.password( userDto.getPassword() );
        user.profilePicturePath( userDto.getProfilePicturePath() );

        return user.build();
    }
```

Comment: Hey GhostCat. I've added edit to original question. There is no any error shown, i see that implementation is missing mapping for ID, and i in UserDto object when i run the program, ID is null.

Comment: How are you calling this mapper ?

Comment: It is Autowired in class and im calling it like this return userMapper.userToUserDto(savedUser); 
where saved user is User object

Comment: And can you add code for builder ? Are you using Lombok ?

Comment: Yep, I'm using lombok. And i added necessary configuration in pom, so mapstruct and lombok can play together.

One more thing, in that generated code, i see base mapper autowired like this 
@Autowired
    private BaseMapper baseMapper;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing (as you have not put `buider` code) the problem is that your builder class does not include parent class field. MapStruct makes some assumption while generating code for mapper. From [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-with-builders) -

> The default implementation of the BuilderProvider assumes the
> following:

1. The type has a parameterless public static builder creation method
   that returns a builder. So for example Person has a public static
   method that returns PersonBuilder.
2. The builder type has a parameterless public method (build method)
   that returns the type being build In our example PersonBuilder has a
   method returning Person.
3. In case there are multiple build methods, MapStruct will look for a
   method called build, if such method exists then this would be used,
   otherwise a compilation error would be created.

If you are using Lombok, you can solve this by using `@SuperBuilder` as -

```
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@ToString
public class UserDto extends BaseDto {
  private String name;
  private String lastName;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String profilePicturePath;
}

@Getter
@SuperBuilder
class BaseDto {
  private Long id;
}

@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@ToString
public class User extends BaseEntity {
  private String name;
  private String lastName;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String profilePicturePath;
}

@Setter
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
class BaseEntity {
  private Long id;
}
```

And generated could looks like -

```
@Override
public User userDtoToUser(UserDto userDto) {
    if ( userDto == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    UserBuilder<?, ?> user = User.builder();

    user.id( userDto.getId() );
    user.name( userDto.getName() );
    user.lastName( userDto.getLastName() );
    user.username( userDto.getUsername() );
    user.password( userDto.getPassword() );
    user.profilePicturePath( userDto.getProfilePicturePath() );

    return user.build();
}
```

Comment: I would like to add **@NoArgsConstructor** and **@AllArgsConstructor** inside BaseDto, BaseEntity class